# POST, with Guzzle, to a web service

Tags: 8

I would like to POST a node to REST API on my Drupal site. On that site, I have enabled the following *Web services* modules:

- HAL
- HTTP Basic Authentication
- REST UI
- RESTful Web Services
- Serialization

The configuration of REST UI looks like this:
[image]

My code is based on [this Guzzle example](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/3-post-for-creating-content-entities):

```
$url = 'http://my-site/node?_format=hal_json';
$auth = ['admin', 'password'];
$body = json_encode([
  'title' => [['value' => '2']],
  'field_bar' => [['value' => 'bar']],
  'type' => [['target_id' => 'bar']],
  '_links' => ['type' => [
    'href' => 'http://my-site/rest/type/node/bar'
  ]],
]);
$headers = [
  'Content-Type' => 'application/hal+json',
  'X-CSRF-Token' => 'my-token',
];

try {
  $response = \Drupal::httpClient()
    ->post($url, ['auth' => $auth, 'body' => $body, 'headers' => $headers]);
  $code = $response->getStatusCode();
  if ($code == 200) {
    \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage($this->t('Success!'));
  }
  else {
    \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage($this->t('Bad response!'), 'error');
  }
}
catch (RequestException $e) {
  \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage($this->t('Foo'), 'error');
  \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage(Psr7\str($e->getRequest()));
  if ($e->hasResponse()) {
    \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage(Psr7\str($e->getResponse()));
  }
  watchdog_exception('foo', $e);
}
```

When it runs, it throws:

> No route found for the specified format hal_json. Supported formats: html.

Full message:

POST /node?_format=hal_json HTTP/1.1 User-Agent: Drupal/8.6.3 (+https://www.drupal.org/) GuzzleHttp/6.3.3 curl/7.54.0 PHP/7.1.14 Authorization: Basic some-string== Host: my-site Content-Type: application/hal+json X-CSRF-Token: my-token {"title":[{"value":"2"}],"field_bar":[{"value":"bar"}],"type":[{"target_id":"bar"}],"_links":{"type":{"href":"http://my-site/rest/type/node/bar"}}}

HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable Cache-Control: must-revalidate, no-cache, private Content-Language: en Content-Type: application/hal+json Date: Sun, 25 Nov 2018 11:19:16 GMT Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT Link: https://my-site/node?_format=html; rel="alternate"; type="text/html" Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=0 Vary: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-Debug-Info: some-string== X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN X-Generator: Drupal 8 (https://www.drupal.org) X-Platform-Cache: MISS X-Platform-Cluster: some-string X-Platform-Processor: some-string X-Platform-Router: some-string X-Request-Id: some-string X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow X-Ua-Compatible: IE=edge Content-Length: 88 {"message":"No route found for the specified format hal_json. Supported formats: html."}

Note: A cURL from the command line works.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I don’t know much about this module, but could it be that the route endpoint does not define more than the default format of html even if the UI says it does?

Comment: Even if I configure manually by importing my own configuration, I still get the same error.

Comment: I opened up my CORS settings and it's working now.